# How can I deny direct access to a directory, but allowing it from a php script?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permissions

I'm developing a web application and I need to save and show images and pdf documents.

I wanted to deny direct access to the images and documents and to its container file. I mean, that when someone try to acess via url to the folder, should receive a 403-forbidden error.

For this I created a .htaccess file inside the folder like this:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Using my web application, via a php script, there is no problem accessing the pdf docments like this

```
header('content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('../../../files/'.$document);
```

But when I try to access the images using `<img style=max-width:100% src=../files/'.$image.'>'` my access is denied and I receive a http status code 403 forbidden.

How can I access the images using my web application, but denying the direct access to the images?

Also I would like to know why I can access the pdf documents, but I can't access the images.

Comment: create a script which will verify that user is logged in and has the right permissions, and serve all files using that script. (aka, create file called file.php, and pass it document id. Script will verify user's access levels, and read file to use. Your img tag will need to be `src='../file.php?img=12'` or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a handler for either of these file types.

Place the files outside of the web accessible file system. i.e. If your web root is /var/www/html then create /var/www/files/ directory and store all your files in there.

```
$file_id = intval($_REQUEST['file_id']);

$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM files WHERE file_id=%d",$file_id);
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
$file = $result->fetch_assoc()

// add business logic for 
// if $user_id is allowed to view $file_id

if (preg_match("/\.pdf$/i",$file['filename'])){
    header('content-type: application/pdf');
} else  if (preg_match("/\.(jpg|gif|png)$/i",$file['filename'])){
    header('content-type: application/pdf');
} else {
    die("Unknown file type");
}

$full_path = sprintf("/var/www/files/%s",$file['filename']);
readfile($full_path);
```

This would allow you to use your application logic to determine which files should be accessed by a user, record the access and keep them out of the web accessible directory.

So instead of using something like this

```
<img style=max-width:100% src=../files/'.$image.'>'
```

I would suggest using a syntax similar to this for handling images

```
<img style=max-width:100% src=/handler.php?file_id='.$file_id.'>'
```

and a link like this for downloading PDFs

```
<img style=max-width:100% src=/handler.php?file_id='.$file_id.'>'
```

It should be pretty straight forward assuming your have a database of PDFs and images. Something simple like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `file_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`file_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Where should I write the first code? Also, what does that?

The second doesn't work because you can still access directly to the files inside the folder.

Comment: I've added a different approach which should help out. I'm assuming your have an access handler for your PDF files and this would be the same handler that you would call for your image handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule,

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

It will allow from your local server address on which your web app is hosted.

Edit:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Use above to turn off directory listing too, it will give forbidden error.

Comment: It doesn't work. I also tried allowinfg from localhost and from ::1. The problem with the last one is that u can still access directly to the folder.

Comment: No, Not Worked.